# Set GRUB timeout to -1 but timeout remains 30

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, hibernate

this is my first time posting here. I tried my best to work this problem out on my own but it didn't work out.

I did't want a timeout on my GRUB boot menu, I wanted it to remain indefinitely until I make a choice. So I edited my GRUB customization file as follows:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT='Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda1)'
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and then I ran

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then tried to hibernate and wake up and the timeout was **still 30 seconds**.
I wanted to know how the timeouts in my **grub.cfg** file look like so I ran this command:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep timeout

  set timeout=30
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=-1
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
    set timeout=-1

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
```

It seems to me like the default timeout is still 30.. I suspect it's a hibernation thing but I have to reboot to make sure if the countdown exists only when I hibernate...

---

EDIT: It definitely is a hibernation thing. When I reboot, the boot menu remains indefinitely, but when I hibernate, it counts down from 30.

---

EDIT2: Nevermind. Sometimes this issue doesn't happen on reboot or hibernation, sometimes it happens with both, sometimes it's either. I have no idea how to troubleshoot the cause with such an unpredictable behaviour..

---

EDIT3: Here are my hibernation configs:

```
sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
  ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: I use the same timeout `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1` and also I un-commented the line `# GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`. Grub menu always waits for input. I never used hibernation though, so try it out and see if it is better then

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible. See OP's **EDIT2**.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it could be a configuration I'm overlooking or something of such. I think I've posted enough troubleshooting info to reproduce this. It's a 50/50 chance so after a couple of hibernations or reboots it will be encountered.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation, in the terminal with `info grub` or online at [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html#Simple-configuration)

```
‘GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE’

    If this option is unset or set to ‘menu’, then GRUB will display the menu and then wait for the timeout set by ‘GRUB_TIMEOUT’ to expire before booting the default entry. Pressing a key interrupts the timeout. 

'GRUB_TIMEOUT'
     Boot the default entry this many seconds after the menu is
     displayed, unless a key is pressed.  The default is '5'.  Set to
     '0' to boot immediately without displaying the menu, or to '-1' to
     wait indefinitely.

     If 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE' is set to 'countdown' or 'hidden', the
     timeout is instead counted before the menu is displayed.
```

So you should set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to 0. And to get the menu being displayed until an entry is chosen aka indefenitvly you must set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` to menu.

Is `GRUB_DEFAULT` correct ? You want to boot into windows  by default ?

Comment: I want my grub menu to **show** indefinitely.
Using GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0 will not make this happen. It will instead take me directly to the default OS.
Which is indeed Windows because I boot on that more (For reasons involving MatLab, AutoCAD, SolidWorks, etc..)